# How to convert UTC hours to EDT hours

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to convert UTC hours to EDT hours by passing hours as input;

Ex: if I pass 14:00 as input I would get 10:00

Could someone recommend any Node JS library or working code snippet more helpful.

Comment: As any other time convertion: add or remove time from current time

Comment: Please note that questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is your target timezone use daylight saving time? If not, you may just decrease 4 hours on original time. Otherwise, you should have a look about some library.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) with the [timezone extension](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/).

An example from the docs:

```
var a = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "Asia/Taipei");
var b = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto");

a.format(); // 2013-11-18T11:55:00+08:00
b.format(); // 2013-11-18T11:55:00-05:00

a.utc().format(); // 2013-11-18T03:55Z
b.utc().format(); // 2013-11-18T16:55Z
```

Comment: I don't have time value to pass as argument

Comment: Hm... Do you mean you don't have a date? Only the clock time?

Comment: In that case, you may want to try just using the current day's date, and setting the time accordingly. Note that you nearly always need a date to get an accurate time... For instance, if in your timezone it's 23:00, but in another timezone it's 05:00-- is that 05:00 today or tomorrow? There is no way to know without dates, so the workaround I mentioned might be your best bet.